# JS Only apply if condition to relevant item

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have a small group of items as shown below.

```
    <div class="item">
        <div class="date">2013-08-08</div>
        <div class="headline"><a data="normal" href="#">Title</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="date">2013-10-08</div>
        <div class="headline"><a data="special" href="#">Title</a></div>
    </div>
```

If the title has a data attribute of special, I want to make the date bold for that item only.
I have the below code to try and do this.

```
    <script>
        if ($(".headline a [data='special']")){
            $( ".date" ).wrap( "<b></b>" );
        }
    </script>
```

However this makes all items bold if the condition is true.
I am familiar with using **this** in JS but not sure how to relate it to another div above.

What is the best way to do this?
I am happy to change the html structure if required as well.

Comment: Is this the selector you're looking for: `$('.item:has(.headline a[data="special"]) .date').wrap('<b>')`?

Comment: Also, `[data]` is not a valid HTML5 attribute.

Comment: Err, why not just add a class instead of a data attribute, and then a `.special .date { font-weight:bold; }` style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(".headline a[data='special']").parent().siblings(".date").wrap("<b></b>");
```

The `parent()` function will select the `div.headline` for a matching `<a>` tag; then, `siblings(".date")` will select children of the parent of `div.headline` (which are called *siblings*) that have the *date* class.

Comment: @Supericy `.date` is a sibling of `.headline`, true, but the tag that's being selected is the `<a>` tag (which is nested one more level)!

Comment: You should use `.css('font-weight', 'bold')` instead of `.wrap('<b></b>')`. Markup should not be used for presentational purposes. If you want to semantically state that this text should be emphasized, use `.wrap(document.createElement('strong'))` instead.

Comment: @TravisKaufman, actually it depends on the context. I think this might actually be a correct use case for the `<b>` element, it's certainly *not* a correct use case for the JS though. This sort of change should be done in the markup directly.

Comment: @TravisKaufman I totally agree with you. However, I stuck with the function call that ak85 was making to explain how to traverse the DOM elements.

Comment: @TravisKaufman, ["The b element represents a span of text to which attention is being drawn for utilitarian purposes without conveying any extra importance and with no implication of an alternate voice or mood"](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-b-element)

Comment: @zzzzBov I believe the W3C [discourage the use of those tags in favor of strong/em or css](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-b-and-i-tags). I honestly don't think there's ever a use case where either using `<strong>` or pure css is less suited than using a `<b>` tag. And in this case, the markup implies that the bolded text *is* important. Which is why I mentioned `<strong>`, because it seems to fit the semantic meaning better. @MariusSchulz is right though this answer is perfectly correct and will do the job, just throwing in my two cents :)

Comment: Some good points here I was just using <b> in here as a quick test to see if the js was working.  I would use a class in my actual site.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'd like to select the `.date` element in `.item` elements which contain `.headline a[data="special"]` elements.

```
$('.item:has(.headline a[data="special"]) .date')
```

will select the correct `.date` elements for my given assumptions, you can then call `.wrap('<b></b>')`.

---

Also note: `[data]` is not a valid [`[data-*]` attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes). You must have a hyphen and a name for custom data attributes.